# How to get location of Test step in cucumber event plugin

Tags: java, cucumber

I am writing a custom plugin for my cucumber tests for which I am trying to find the location of the step. I am using below code in the my event plugin.

```
     private void EHTestCaseStarted(TestCaseStarted event) {
      
            //get Location of first step
            int lineNumber =-1;
            int colNumber = -1;
            List<TestStep> steps = event.getTestCase().getTestSteps();
            for(TestStep step:steps)
            {
                
                if(step.getClass().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("class io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep"))
                {
                    System.out.println(step.getCodeLocation());
                }

            } 
}
```

I tried casting it to PickLeStepTestStep but it was throws unable to cast exception as it is not accessible in cucumber version 6.9.0

Comment: Try casting to https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/plugin/src/main/java/io/cucumber/plugin/event/PickleStepTestStep.java

Comment: it seems i was casting hookstep that is why is was throwing cast execptio

Comment: is there a way to skip the steps from background steps?